# Julia and dbscan clustering: how extract elements from resulting structure?

Tags: indexing, types, julia, cluster-analysis, dbscan

Warning: this is from a julia n00b!

After performing `dbscan` on a **point coordinate array** in Julia. (Note that this is not the 'distance based method' that returns 'assignments' as part of the result structure, but the 'adjacency list' method). [Documentation here](https://clusteringjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dbscan.html). I attempt to access the vector containing the indices, but I am at a loss when trying to retrieve the members of individual clusters:

```
dbr = dbscan(pointcoordinates, .1, min_neighbors = 10, min_cluster_size = 10)

13-element Array{DbscanCluster,1}:
 DbscanCluster(17, [4, 12, 84, 90, 94, 675, 676, 737, 873, 965], [27, 108, 177, 880, 954, 1050, 1067])
 DbscanCluster(10, Int64[], [46, 48, 51, 57, 188, 225, 226, 228, 270, 542])
 DbscanCluster(11, [48, 51, 228], [46, 49, 57, 188, 225, 226, 270, 542])
 DbscanCluster(14, [418, 759, 832, 988, 1046], [830, 831, 855, 865, 989, 991, 996, 1021, 1070])
 DbscanCluster(10, Int64[], [624, 654, 664, 803, 805, 821, 859, 987, 1057, 1069])
```

It is easy to retrieve a single cluster from the array:

```
> dbr[1]

DbscanCluster(17, [4, 12, 84, 90, 94, 675, 676, 737, 873, 965], [27, 108, 177, 880, 954, 1050, 1067])
```

But how do i get the stuff inside DBscanCluster?

```
a = dbr[1]

DbscanCluster(17, [4, 12, 84, 90, 94, 675, 676, 737, 873, 965], [27, 108, 177, 880, 954, 1050, 1067])
In [258]:

a[1]
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::DbscanCluster, ::Int64)
```

Thank you for your help, and sorry if I am missing something glaring!

Answer (score 1):

What makes you say that `DbscanCluster` is a child of array?

```
julia> DbscanCluster <: AbstractArray
false
```

You might be confused by `Array{DbscanCluster,1}` in your result, but this just tells you that the object returned by the `dbscan` call is an `Array` the elements of which are of type `DbscanCluster` - this does not tell you anything about whether those elements themselves are subtypes of `Array`.

As for how to get the indexes, the [docs](https://juliastats.org/Clustering.jl/stable/dbscan.html#Clustering.DbscanResult) for `DbscanResult` show that the type has three fields:

- `seeds::Vector{Int}`: indices of cluster starting points
- `assignments::Vector{Int}`: vector of clusters indices, where each point was assigned to
- `counts::Vector{Int}`: cluster sizes (number of assigned points)

each of which you can access with dot notation by doing e.g. `drb[1].assignments`.

If you want to get say the counts for all the 13 clusters in your results, you can broadcast `getproperty` like so:

```
getproperty.(drb, :counts)
```

Note that counts does not exist for in the case of the "adjacency lists" method of dbscan, one can use:

```
getproperty.(drb, :core_indices)
```

Comment: And, thanks for pointing me to ```getproperty()```!

Comment: and this is what worked for me: ```getproperty.(dbr, :core_indices)```. I learned a lot from how to retrieve the contents within some datastructure via broadcasting, so I thank you a third time.